# Cobra Chart Plot with Python

Tags: python, excel

Here is my data I would like to plot.
The aim is plot the first column (Baseline Date) against columns A B C D etcc...

```
    Baseline Date   A             B         C           D          E
0   14/08/2020  15/10/2020  15/10/2020  19/11/2020  29/10/2020  13/10/2020
1   21/08/2020  20/03/2021  13/05/2022  10/12/2020  3/12/2020   5/11/2020
2   28/08/2020  10/03/2021  3/05/2022   30/11/2020  23/11/2020  26/10/2020
3   4/09/2020   13/03/2021  6/05/2022   3/12/2020   26/11/2020  29/10/2020
4   11/09/2020  18/03/2021  11/05/2022  8/12/2020   1/12/2020   3/11/2020
5   18/09/2020  21/03/2021  14/05/2022  11/12/2020  4/12/2020   6/11/2020
6   25/09/2020  19/03/2021  12/05/2022  9/12/2020   2/12/2020   4/11/2020
7   2/10/2020   22/03/2021  15/05/2022  12/12/2020  5/12/2020   7/11/2020
8   9/10/2020   28/03/2021  21/05/2022  18/12/2020  11/12/2020  13/11/2020
9   16/10/2020  31/03/2021  24/05/2022  21/12/2020  14/12/2020  16/11/2020
10  23/10/2020  3/04/2021   27/05/2022  24/12/2020  17/12/2020  19/11/2020
11  30/10/2020  9/04/2021   2/06/2022   30/12/2020  23/12/2020  25/11/2020
12  6/11/2020   9/04/2021   2/06/2022   30/12/2020  23/12/2020  25/11/2020
```

The graph should look something like this. Comparing Baseline column vs A B C D etc.
Is this type of graph possible in Python ? This is called  Cobra chart, shows the deviation from the baseline date
[image]

I have tried this, getting closer, does not look quite as good as excel.

```
figure(num=None, figsize=(30, 16), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
baseline_date = cobra_df['Baseline Date']
plt.plot(Col_a, baseline_date, label="A")
plt.plot(Col_b, baseline_date, label="B")
plt.plot(Col_c, baseline_date, label="C")
plt.plot(Col_d, baseline_date, label="D")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Bdate")
plt.title("Cobra Chart")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use matplotlib.
example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ylabel("activity date")
plt.xlabel("data date")
plt.plot(data_date_list1, activity_date_list1, color="blue")
plt.plot(data_date_list2, activity_date_list2, color="yellow")
plt.show()
```

this will show almost exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks forever. Any Idea how to plot curve fit instead of straight lines ?

Comment: I have no idea.